# Oracle : How can i find the holiday in a business day?

Tags: database, oracle

Consider there are 3 different centers across the country,which have their different holidays schedule.Now i want to find  that the current date is the business day or not(eliminate saturaday ,sunday and Holidays).

tell me,Which one is feasible? Can i store the details of the holiday with description in 3 separate tables for 3 different centers or in a 3 separate file? is it possible to read the file using PL\SQl?

Comment: It's pretty easy. You build yourself a monopoly and when you feel like taking a break, you raise your rates, just because you can. In this manner, you find the holiday in every business day, because you don't actually need to work to get any money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 additional tables, say PLACE and HOLIDAYS, 1 PLACE = many HOLIDAYS

PLACE will have 3 records which will correspond to the place of your centers which have different holidays. Each record in PLACE table will have corresponding holiday schedule e.g. create MONTH and DAY columns so you can query them and compare them to your current date.

This will make your design flexible rather than hardcoding 3 separate tables for 3 different centers.  Later if you add a center in a place with different holiday schedule, you can just add a record instead of creating another table.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this without using table?.Because we need to maintain the table each and every table (i.e) every year we need to update the holidays of each centers.Plz Give me any other solution?if possible

Comment: Does your government change holidays each year? If so, do you expect many changes? Maintaining HOLIDAYS table should be okay, you should create a maintenance page for this and let the centers maintain them.  If this is a web application, then it should be easy.